# How to change bubble color in google bubble chart

Tags: bubble-chart

How can I change google bubble chart bubble color ?.i didnt find any soultion from their api.

I need 
Extreme bubble color = 'Red' or color hex code 
High bubble color = 'Orange' or color hex code 
Medium bubble color = 'yellow' or color hex code 
Low bubble color = 'green' or color hex code

I giving api and my test code below.please check and give me a solution. pls help

[Google Bubble Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart#configuration-options)
This is the google bubble chart api link

Test Code Below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSeriesChart);

    function drawSeriesChart() {


      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['core', 'Xscore', 'Yscore', 'Level',     'Size'],
        ['12.00',    6,              6,      'EXTREME',  4],
        ['4.84',    2.84,              1.36,      'MEDIUM',         2],
        ['6.6',    5.6,               1.84,      'HIGH',         3],
        ['7.73',    5.73,              2.78,      'HIGH',    3],
        ['7.05',    5.05,              2,         'MEDIUM',         2],
        ['4.49',    3.49,              1.7,       'LOW',    1],
        ['9.09',    4.09,              4.77,      'HIGH',    3],
        ['4.55',    2.55,              2.96,      'LOW',    1],
        ['4.6',    2.6,               1.54,      'LOW',         1],
        ['6',    3.6,               2.54,      'MEDIUM',         2],
        ['7.6',    3.6,               3.54,      'HIGH',         3],
        ['7.6',    3.6,               3.54,      'HIGH',         3],
        ['7.7',    3.6,               3.54,      'HIGH',         3],        
        ['10.6',    5.6,               4.54,      'HIGH',         3],
        ['6.6',    4.6,               1.24,      'MEDIUM',         2],
        ['3.6',    1.6,               1.34,      'LOW',         1],
        ['6.6',    1.6,               5.14,      'HIGH',         3],
        ['7.7',    1.7,               5.54,      'HIGH',         3],
        ['6.8',    1.8,               4.54,      'HIGH',         3],
        ['11.6',    5.6,               5.54,      'EXTREME',         4],
        ['7.09',    5.09,              2.05,      'HIGH',  3]
      ]);
      var options = {
        title: '',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        hAxis: {title: 'Xscore', ticks: [1,2,3,4,5,6], textStyle:{color:'#999',bold:'1'},gridlines: {color: '#696966'},titleTextStyle:{italic:'0'}},
        vAxis: {title: 'Yscore', ticks: [1,2,3,4,5,6],textStyle:{color:'#999',bold:'1'},gridlines: {color: '#696966'},titleTextStyle:{italic:'0'}},
        bubble: {textStyle: {fontSize: 9,color:'#FFFFFF',auraColor:'none'}},
        chartArea:{backgroundColor:'#4c4c4b'},
        legend: { position: 'none' },
        animation:{easing:'in'}

      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('series_chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>


  <div class="widget-content shortcuts">
    <div id="series_chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 800px;"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can find the API here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart

Comment: yes. I know this link and got this chart from here..but i didn't find any option to change bubble colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. I dropped the 'Level' column from your data, defined the value/color pairings in the appropriate arrays in colorAxis, and hid the legend for same:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSeriesChart);

function drawSeriesChart() {


  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['core', 'Xscore', 'Yscore', 'Size'],
    ['12.00',    6,              6,      4],
    ['4.84',    2.84,              1.36,           2],
    ['6.6',    5.6,               1.84,            3],
    ['7.73',    5.73,              2.78,       3],
    ['7.05',    5.05,              2,               2],
    ['4.49',    3.49,              1.7,        1],
    ['9.09',    4.09,              4.77,         3],
    ['4.55',    2.55,              2.96,        1],
    ['4.6',    2.6,               1.54,           1],
    ['6',    3.6,               2.54,            2],
    ['7.6',    3.6,               3.54,              3],
    ['7.6',    3.6,               3.54,          3],
    ['7.7',    3.6,               3.54,              3],        
    ['10.6',    5.6,               4.54,        3],
    ['6.6',    4.6,               1.24,              2],
    ['3.6',    1.6,               1.34,          1],
    ['6.6',    1.6,               5.14,             3],
    ['7.7',    1.7,               5.54,             3],
    ['6.8',    1.8,               4.54,            3],
    ['11.6',    5.6,               5.54,            4],
    ['7.09',    5.09,              2.05,       3]
  ]);
  var options = {
    title: '',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    hAxis: {title: 'Xscore', ticks: [1,2,3,4,5,6], textStyle:{color:'#999',bold:'1'},gridlines: {color: '#696966'},titleTextStyle:{italic:'0'}},
    vAxis: {title: 'Yscore', ticks: [1,2,3,4,5,6],textStyle:{color:'#999',bold:'1'},gridlines: {color: '#696966'},titleTextStyle:{italic:'0'}},
    bubble: {textStyle: {fontSize: 9,color:'#FFFFFF',auraColor:'none'}},
    colorAxis: {values: [1, 2, 3, 4], colors: ['green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'], legend: {position: 'none'}},
    chartArea:{backgroundColor:'#4c4c4b'},
    legend: { position: 'none' },
    animation:{easing:'in'}

  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('series_chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>


<div class="widget-content shortcuts">
<div id="series_chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 800px;"></div>
</div>
```

If this helps, please let me know. Today was my first time using Google Charts and I came here looking for the same info, then figured it out on my own. If there's a better way to do it, I'm eager to learn. :)

Comment: Thanx alot B.Rossow.. it's working :) . except 1,2,3,4 we cant set colour axis with string LOW MEDIUM HIGH end EXTREME right?. also i need to set only first 3 values on tooltip.. do you know that?

Answer (score 2):

In my example (for Bubble Chart), I wanted different colors based on my "Type" column, and then the "Severity" column would make my bubbles big or small.

The best way I found to do this is to first insert some bogus data, but in order of the colors you want to use.  Then, tell the graph (using hAxis.viewWindow.max & min, as well as vAxis.viewWindow.max & min) NOT to show your bogus data points.

Example:

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['ID', 'Value',     'OtherVal',       'Type',     'Severity'],
    
    // First, set some bogus, just so we can establish color (in order) for the 'Type' column.
    ['',    0,               0,      'Strategic',      1],
    ['',    0,              0,      'Financial',       2],
    ['',    0,               0,      'Compliance',     3],
    ['',    0,              0,      'Operational',     4],
    ['',    0,              0,      'Reputational',    5],
    
    // We can now put in our "real" data....
    
    ['',    5001,              100,      'Strategic',      1],
    ['',    5002.2,            101,      'Financial',      2],
    ['',    5002.7,            101,      'Compliance',     5],
    ['',    5004,              103,      'Operational',    4],
    ['',    5005,              104,      'Reputational',   2],
    ['',    5005.4,            105,      'Compliance',     2],
    ['',    5005.1,            106,      'Financial',      2],
    ['',    5008,              105,      'Strategic',      4],
    ['',    5009,              108,      'Compliance',     4],
    ['',    5009.1,            109,      'Operational',    2],
    ['',    5011,              104,      'Operational',    2],
    ['',    5012,              102,      'Operational',    4]
  ]);
```

When we go to create the options for our chart, we make sure we specify our colors, and to not show anything before our datapoints....

```
  var options = {
    title: 'Incidents by Department',
    hAxis: {viewWindow: {min: 5000, max: 5013}},
    vAxis: {viewWindow: {min: 99, max: 110}},
    colors: ['black', 'darkgreen', '#B22222', '#888', 'purple'],    
  };
```

Comment: Hey this helped. Thanks for sharing this. This does change the color of each bubble and yet maintains the size of the Bubble. However, i wanted to know can we manipulate Tooltip in any way possible. Lets say i want to show couple of more fields than already showing. Really appreciate your help.